# Split imbalanced (binary) data set so test set has equal number of false and positive samples

Tags: python, classification, train-test-split

I am trying to apply a NN to a binary classification problem with high class imbalance; 28k False (0.) and 68k True (1.). Is it possible to use stratify with train_test_split to ensure the proportion of True and False events is the same in the test set, but not the train set? For example; Test set - 14k False, 14k true. Train set - 14k False, 54k True.